# Passing the language parameter to the next page (url) when submitting the form

Tags: php, laravel, routes, translation, url-parameters

I'm having problems with getting the right language parameter in the url when submitting a form.
My application has two possible language parameters: `de` and `en`.

I've made a middleware called setLocale.php with this function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    return $next($request);
}
```

this is the route in web.php:

```
Route::post('/{locale?}/ticket', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

and here is the form action:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('validation') }}">
```

When I want to submit the form and the input is validated you should get to the route I've shown you above.
But the url will only be: `/ticket` instead of `en/ticket` or `de/ticket`.

By the way, you get to the form site via links, so the language parameters are static like this:

```
Route::get('/en/index/{param1?}/{param2?}', 'TicketController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/de/index/{param1?}/{param2?}', 'TicketController@index')->name('index');
```

- How do I get the language parameter from the form page ('/**en**/index/[..]') in the url of the validation page, therefore in the form action?
- Shouldn't the `handle` function in the `setLocale.php` middleware get me the language parameter when trying to submit the form?
  If yes, how can I achieve passing it to the next page (via the form action)?

**EDIT**

It works fine when I edit the form action like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('validation', app()->getLocale()) }}">
```

Would this be a good solution?

Comment: Would you find it simpler to use the formRequest to handle this?

Comment: @GingaWRATH what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @GingaWRATH I use formRequest to handle validation, my problem is when the form is submitted; i'm not able to get the language parameter of the form page to the next page

Comment: Did not you forget to reference your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel` with `\App\Http\Middleware\setLocale::class`?

Comment: @iArcadia nope, i did this

Comment: You could always set the language in the cookies which you can retrieve in your controller, or add them into your $request when POSTing to the controller as an alternative.

Comment: Maybe you could use [route binding (see "Customizing The Resolution Logic")](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) to always set the locale to the current one.

Comment: @Thomas If I did this, I would replace the `TicketConroller@store` with a function that gets the Locale and uses it for the parameter, right? What would happen to the Controller method? I need to call it somewhere then..

Comment: You can, but I don't think you need to. The idea is that when Laravel generates the URL for the `validation` route, it will always have a value for `{locale}`, even if you don't explicitly pass one.

Comment: @Thomas since you're from Zürich, do you speak german? It would make it easier for me to explain

Comment: Let's continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192439/room-for-passing-the-language-parameter-to-the-next-page-url-when-submitting-t)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your problem is that the `{locale}` parameter has no value if you don't explicitly pass one to the `route()` function. You can use [route binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) (see "Customizing The Resolution Logic") to guarantee that it will always have a value, falling back on the current locale:

```php
Route::bind('locale', function ($value) {
    if (!$value) {
        $value = app()->getLocale();
    }

    return $value;
});
```

This instructs Laravel to call this function whenever it sees a route parameter named `locale` and use its return value. And if there's no value for the parameter, it returns the current locale.

But be aware that this will affect **all** URL parameters named `locale`. If you have any route whose `locale` parameter should be allowed to be empty, you will have to rename in in one of the routes.